# Set a kind name independently of the model name (App Engine datastore)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As a Python programmer, I like my code to be reusable, I'm trying to avoid kind name conflicts in my code (where two different models share the same kind name).

Currently I just prepend some meaningful text to the model's class name, but this is awfully unpythonic.

Being able to explicitly set the model's kind will solve my problem, but I can't find out how to do this, does anyone know how?

Comment: Can you post an example or two of what sort of conflicts you're talking about?  How is it that you're running into models with the same class name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just override the `kind()` method of your class:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  @classmethod
  def kind(cls):
    return 'prefix_%s' % super(MyModel, cls).kind()
```

You can define a custom baseclass that does this for you:

```
class ModuleModel(db.Model):
  @classmethod
  def kind(cls):
    return '%s_%s' % (cls.__module__, super(ModuleModel, cls).kind())
```

Any class that extends ModuleModel will have the name of the module it's defined in prefixed to the kind name.