# Set an entity kind name different from a class name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Is there any way how to set a kind name different from a class name used in my Google App Engine?

I am using Java and JDO to access a datastore.

---

There a question about the similar issue in Python. It seems answered. [Set a kind name independently of the model name (App Engine datastore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300387/set-a-kind-name-independently-of-the-model-name-app-engine-datastore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooops... It was quite easy to achieve:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "person")
public class PersonEntity {
    // ...
}
```