# NDB - Setting kind name independently of model name

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Similar to the question asked here:

[Set a kind name independently of the model name (App Engine datastore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300387/set-a-kind-name-independently-of-the-model-name-app-engine-datastore)

but instead for NDB.

My use case is as follows:

We modified our db code to use prefixes for the datastore kind names (e.g. instead of 'Car' it uses ModuleName_Car). We are now upgrading to NDB and don't have a way to change 'Car' to ModuleName_Car, and subsequently ndb is unable to read existing data. Any workarounds that don't involve naming my model 'ModuleName_Car(ndb.Model)' ?

Comment: I've found snooping around in the NDB (and other SDK module) sources to be more effective than reading the GAE documentation in many cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NDB Cheat Sheet doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) hinted enough (via `_get_kind()`) to point me to [this section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities):

> The kind is normally the name of the model class to which
>   the entity belongs ("Account" in the example above), but can be
>   changed to some other string by overriding the classmethod
>   _get_kind().

Answer (score 1):

To expand on David's answer

```
class NdbCredential(ndb.Expando):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def _get_kind(cls):
        return 'Credential'
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached this problem for the specific use case of mixing db and ndb Models/Keys.

Suppose your db class was defined as:

```
class CarModel(db.Model):
  brand = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=Brand)
```

And db.ReferenceProperty Brand identified itself with brand.kind() == "my_Brand". The corresponding ndb.Model might look like:

```
class CarModel(ndb.Model):
  brand = KeyProperty(kind="my_Brand")
```

This should solve your issue since myBrand is properly referenced by the kind. In my case, I specifically wanted to mix db.Key into the ndb.Model by assigning the field by the ndb.Key, db.Key, or db.Model and then retrieving a db.Key to be used in query filters and other matching logic. I subclassed ndb.KeyProperty to handle the behavior as follows (code golf/corrections welcome):

```
class DbReferenceProperty:
  @staticmethod
  def _db_to_ndb_key(entity):
    if entity is None:
      return None
    ndb_key = ndb.Key.from_old_key(entity) if type(entity) == db.Key else ndb.Key.from_old_key(entity.key())

   #Overrides ndb.KeyProperty method
  def _validate(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, ndb.Key) and not isinstance(value, db.Key) and not isinstance(value, db.Model):
      raise TypeError("Unexpected type: %s" % repr(value))

  #Overrides ndb.KeyProperty method
  def _to_base_type(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, db.Key) or isinstance(value, db.Model):
      value = DbReferenceProperty._db_to_ndb_key(value)
    return value  

  #Overrides ndb.KeyProperty method
  def _from_base_type(self, value):
    prop_id, kind_str = value.id(), value.kind()
    db_key = db.Key.from_path(kind_str, prop_id)
    return db_key
```